Google Sheets Run Function in all sheets
I'm trying to run a function to count the number of cells that have a certain background color accross all sheets. The cell color referenced is in the Practice sheet A6.
Here is the App Script:
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
   var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
   var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
   for (i= 0; i<8; i++) {
   var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
   var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
   var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
   var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
   var countCells = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
      for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
         if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
            countCells = countCells + 1;
   return countCells;
   }
};

Here is calling the function:
=countColoredCells(A:A,'Practice Sheet'!A6)

The function is only returning the coloured cells in the current sheet and not the entire google spreadsheet.
What am I doing wrong?
I tried adding the for loop to run the script through each sheet.

Use Spreadsheet.getSheets(), like this:
function countColoredCells(countRange, colorRef) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const formula = ss.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  let searchColor, countRangeA1;
  try {
    const colorRefA1 = formula.match(/,(.+)\)/).pop().trim();
    searchColor = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(colorRefA1).getBackground();
    countRangeA1 = formula.match(/\((.+),/).pop().trim();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Bad arguments.');
  }
  let count = 0;
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    count += sheet.getRange(countRangeA1).getBackgrounds()
      .flat()
      .filter(c => c === searchColor)
      .length
  });
  return count;
}

See
Spreadsheet.getSheets(),
Array.forEach(),
Array.flat(),
Array.filter().
and
try...catch.

So I'm trying to get the sum cell to update automatically when a cell changes color. I have added a trigger to run the function when something in the spreadsheet changes. I keep getting the return of bad argument

That is not part of the original question. Ask only one question per post. See What should I do when someone answers my question?
